# Why trim() give me String Constant Pool reference?

Tags: java, string, compare

I am exploring String Constant Pool and Heap memory.

```
if("String".trim() == "String")
    System.out.println("Equal");
else
    System.out.println("Not Equal");
```

**Output**

```
Equal
```

And If I add a space in the String before trim, It will give Not Equal output

```
if("String  ".trim() == "String")
    System.out.println("Equal");
else
    System.out.println("Not Equal");
```

**Output**

```
Not Equal
```

Can you explain me above scenario?

And How can I see Heap Memory and String Constant Pool?

Comment: because if trim() does not change the String it will just return `this` aka the original String object itself.

Comment: because String are immutable

Comment: Unrelated: don't get into the habit of having if/then/else blocks **without** using { braces }. Always use { braces }.

Comment: @nafas the "equality" is done on the returned String (aka the new one or itself if needed)

Comment: @nafas This is correct, but not important here.

Comment: You could check the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java#String.trim%28%29).

Answer (score 7):

The  (Java 8) [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) for `String.trim()` state:

> Returns:  A string whose value is this string, with any leading and trailing white space removed, **or this string if it has no leading or trailing white space**.

Since `"String"` has no leading or trailing spaces, `trim()` is returning the `"String"` object.

On the other hand `"String  "` has trailing spaces, so a different `String` object is returned<sup>1</sup>.

BTW: It is not called the "string constant pool".  All strings are constant (immutable).  You might be be talking about all strings that are the result of the evaluation of a compile time *constant expression*.  However, the string pool can also contain strings that were added by a `String.intern()` call on a dynamically created string.  The correct term is the "string pool".

---

<sup>1 - It happens that this object is a different object to the one that represents the `"String"`.  However, a careful reading of the javadoc will reveal that the spec does not require this to be the case.  In a different (hypothetical) version of Java, the `trim()` method *could* return the `"String"` object and still conform to the spec.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

`trim()` method can return the same instance or a totally new created string object, you can verify that in the source code of the method:

```
 return ((st > 0) || (len < value.length)) ? substring(st, len) : this;
```

so it will depends wether this condition meet or not

```
((st > 0) || (len < value.length))
```

now when you do:  `"String".trim() == "String"` the condition doesnt meet so you will compare the reference of the literal "String"

on the option left, a new object is created and the comparison using == returns false....

Answer (score 0):

The second example shows "Not Equal" because,

> The method [trim()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) returns a **copy** of this string with leading and trailing white space removed, or this string if it has no leading or trailing white space.

The word copy is important.

Comment: Actually, the javadoc doesn't use the word "copy" at all.  I don't know where you have gotten the text you are quoting, but it is not the official documentation ... and it is (IMO) misleading.

Comment: @Tom, copy means it is a new object with its new address. How "The word copy is important" not important for question?

Comment: @StephenC I have linked documentation under word 'trim()'

Comment: Ah ... I see.  You are quoting >>old<< documentation.  Please see what the the Javadoc for Java 8 says.   And I agree the Tom.  The question is actually asking about the case where `trim()` *does not* return a copy!

Answer (score -2):

Strings are objects, so comparing Strings with == is not the right choice. Trim returns a String, then you need to compare it to another String using equals, even if the string is not wrapped into a variable. Try using:

System.out.println(" this is a string ".trim());

String test = " this is a string ";
System.out.println(test.trim());

both are going to give the same answer: "this is a string"

I your case you should use:

```
"string".trim().equals("string")
```

which will give you the right answer.

Comment: This does not answer the question.